# model expression not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs, expression

The expression is not getting updated with value I type in text box.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script>
           var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
           app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
                $scope.name="asdfsdf";
           });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl" >
        <input type="text" ng-bind="name" /> {{name}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change ng-bind to ng-model.....ng-model provides two-way binding where as ng-bind provides only one-way binding.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script>
           var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
           app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
                $scope.name="asdfsdf";
           });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl" >
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> {{name}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ng-bind` to `ng-model` to update the value of input.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>Angular Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.name = "asdfsdf";
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" />{{name}}
</body>

</html>
```